# How do I bundle bcrypt in a yarn workspace monorepo using webpack and serverless-framework?

Tags: node.js, webpack, serverless-framework, yarn-workspaces

I'm trying to package a monorepo application for deployment with serverless.  The monorepo uses yarn workspaces and lerna.  To create the packages for deployment, we're using webpack.  The project structure looks like:

Here is the project structure inside monorepo:

common
- shared_project_1
-- package.json
- shared_project_2
-- package.json
services
- service_1
-- package.json
-- serverless.yml
-- webpack.config.js
- service_2
-- package.json
-- serverless.yml
-- webpack.config.js
package.json
lerna.json

commom/shared_project_1/package.json:

```
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.4"
  }
```

services/service_1/package.json:

```
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "serverless webpack --stage development"
  }
```

services/service_1/serverless.yml:

```
service:
  name: service-1

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10

custom:
  webpack:
    includeModules:
      forceExclude:
        - aws-sdk
    packager: yarn

functions:
<functions here>

package:
  exclude:
    - coverage/**

plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
```

package.json:

```
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "services/*",
      "common/*"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "export NODE_ENV=development && lerna run --concurrency 1 build"
  }
```

lerna.json:

```
{
  "packages": [
    "services/*"
  ],
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "npmClient": "yarn",
  "useWorkspaces": true
}
```

The error I get when Serverless reaches 'Serverless: Bundling with Webpack..."' is:

> WARNING in /Users/me/Projects/monorepo/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js 6:15-36
>   Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>    @ /Users/me/Projects/monorepo/common/shared_project_1/src/tables/users.js
>    @ /Users/me/Projects/monorepo/common/shared_project_1/src/connection.js
>    @ ./src/dashboard-snapshots.js
>
> WARNING in /Users//Projects/monorepo/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js 20:22-48
>   Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>    @ /Users/me/Projects/monorepo/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js
>    @ /Users/me/Projects/monorepo/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js
>    @ /Users/me/Projects/monorepo/common/shared_project_1/src/tables/users.js
>    @ /Users/me/Projects/monorepo/common/shared_project_1/src/connection.js
>    @ ./src/dashboard-snapshots.js
>
> WARNING in /Users/me/Projects/monorepo/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/versioning.js 17:20-67
>   Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>    @ /Users/me/Projects/monorepo/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js
>    @ /Users/me/Projects/monorepo/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js
>    @ /Users/me/Projects/monorepo/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js
>    @ /Users/me/Projects/monorepo/common/shared_project_1/src/tables/users.js
>    @ /Users/me/Projects/monorepo/common/shared_project_1/src/connection.js
>    @ ./src/dashboard-snapshots.js
>
> WARNING in /Users/me/Projects/monorepo/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'npm' in '/Users/me/Projects/monorepo/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util'
>    @ /Users/me/Projects/monorepo/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js
>    @ /Users/me/Projects/monorepo/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib sync ^./.*$
>    @ /Users/me/Projects/monorepo/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js
>    @ /Users/me/Projects/monorepo/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js
>    @ /Users/me/Projects/monorepo/coinfo Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

I have tried adding bcrypt to the nohoist workspace config based on suggestions from other questions but that just changes the path in the error message.  I have globally installed node-pre-gyp and node-gyp; makes no difference.  Clearly I'm not understanding how these pieces all fit together.  What changes do I need to make to get the workspace to bundle the bcrypt dependency correctly for deploying into AWS?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, maybe @Corin could ask a question targeted at bcrypt and bundling it with webpack, but in no way the two are duplicates!!!